# Identifying curves with each other

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to read Spivak's Differential Geometry and it seems that the first chapter contains many notions which are not treated rigorously.

Maybe I am not understanding enough, but the notion of identifying curves/points with each other isn't so clear to me.

He explained rigorously how to identify antipodal points with each other and that was a satisfactory explanation. However, it doesn't seem obvious to me how to rigorously define "identifications" in general.

For example, take the case of identifying the boundaries of two manifolds together. How would I make that rigorous?

Also, how would this work with other concepts of manifolds? It all seems very fuzzy to me. Intuitively, this would all go well, but rigorously, I just can't see anything.

Am I supposed to take it intuitively in this book, perhaps because it contains harder concepts beyond the scope of this book, or is there something important which I am missing?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Equivalence_class.2C_quotient_set.2C_partition

Comment: It's technically two related questions. First is how to make the concept of identifying points (other than antipodal points) rigorous. The other is whether it's supposed to be this way in the book (non-rigorous) or I'm missing something.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is that all it is? From the antipodal points example, I thought there'd something really complicated out there...

Comment: Well, there's a bit more going on because e.g. for identifying boundaries, you also want a manifold structure on the result, and in particular a topology. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology) for a start. (Getting a smooth structure is more involved.)

Comment: I see... It's quite bad that I have only the slightest acquaintance with topology. I think taking things intuitively with this will not be so bad (I will come back to it later when I've gotten a grasp in topology.) Also, if you've read this book, is the first chapter supposed to be hand-wavy and non-rigorous or am I missing something?

Comment: Also, if you would compile your comment into an answer so I could accept it, that would be great.

Comment: I guess your first question has been answered. As for the second I feel uneasy about it cause I'm under the impression that a rant is lurking here behind the scenes. If not: differential geometry can be made as precise as any other branch of Math (and if I remember correctly, this is done quite well in the five volumes of Spivaks 'Introduction' to the topic) but is also often heavily relying on intuition in order to grasp the concepts or conceive the idea of a proof. This aspect is also  accounted for in these books. I, personally, found this quite helpful.

Comment: Yes, it is helpful, but as Qiaochu showed, the rigour is not complete. I am fine with relying on intuition for these parts (at least for now, till I read more on algebra+topology later) as long as it is supposed to be so. I'd still like to know if I'm missing something by seeing it as non-rigorous (the first chapter).